# Proving the derivative of a function by induction

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $x,x_0 \in A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, $x \neq x_0$, and $f: A \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfy that $\partial^\alpha f$ exists and is differentiable on the line segment $L = \{(1-t)x_0 + tx \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid t \in [0,1]\}$. I have to prove the following identity by induction on $j$:
\begin{equation*}
    F^{(j)}(t) = \sum_{|\alpha| = j} \frac{j!}{\alpha!}(\partial^\alpha f)((1-t)x_0 + tx)(x - x_0)^\alpha,
\end{equation*}
where $F: (-r,1+r) \to \mathbb{R}$ is defined by $F(t) = f((1-t)x_0 + tx)$ for some $r \in \mathbb{R_{>0}}$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb{N}_0^n$ is a multi-index. The partial derivative $\partial^\alpha$ is defined by $\partial^\alpha = \prod^n_{i=1}\partial_i^{\alpha_i}$, where $\partial_i^{\alpha_i} = \partial^{\alpha_i}/\partial^{\alpha_i}x_i$.

I have proven the base case, but I'm unsure how to go about differentiating the right-hand side of

\begin{equation}
    F^{(k)}(t) = \sum_{|\alpha| = k} \frac{k!}{\alpha!}(\partial^\alpha f)((1-t)x_0 + tx)(x - x_0)^\alpha
\end{equation}

for the induction step. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please add assumptions of $f$ (such as "infinitely often differentiable" or similar) and on $A$ (open? convex or star-shaped?). You seem to need convexity (or similar) to define $F$, since the line segment from $x_{0}$ to $x$ needs to lie in $A$. Please define the domain of $F$, e.g. $F\colon [0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ or similar. Thanks!

Comment: @iljusch I added the remaining assumptions